# Show that $\int_{I} |f(x)|^p dx \leq \int_{I \times I} |f(x)+g(y)|^{p}dxdy$ if $\int_{I} g(y)dy = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be two integrable functions on $I = [0,1]$. Show that for $p \geq 1$, $$\int_{I} |f(x)|^p dx \leq \int_{I \times I} |f(x)+g(y)|^{p}dxdy$$ if $\int_{I} g(y)dy = 0$.

I do not even know where to start. Probably I should start by viewing $\int_{I}|f(x)|^p = \int_{I \times I} |f(x)|^pdxdy$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RHS $\geq \int_0^{1} |\int_0^{1} [f(x)+g(y)] dy|^{p} dx=\int_0^{1} |f(x)|^{p} dx$. The first step follows from Holder's inequality: $|\int h(y)\, dy | \leq (\int|h(y)|^{p}\, dy)^{1/p}$. Take $h(y)=f(x)+g(y)$ with $x$ fixed.